# Magento : System Config page is not loading properly

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

Its recently installed Magento on localhost. System config page takes long time to load, and return partially loaded page

Have tried to restart Apache and done setup:upgrade, but issue still there.
No errors are shown in Apache Log and Magento Logs.

**Versions**

- Magento CLI version 2.2.5
- PHP 7.1.21 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2018
  23:20:07) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 ) Zend Engine v3.1.0,
  Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
- Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) Server built:   Jul 10 2018
  09:24:15

**Partially Loaded System Config Page** 
[image: Partial loaded page]

**If reset is clicked in screen above, and public and private key is entered, it return same partial loaded page with message Credentials Saved**

[image]

Comment: is opcache installed? Check the magento stack requirements [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Comment: I think its not installed. Its running on Windows 10, will check if there is a simple way to install it

Comment: opcache enabled, this time it returned page quickly, but it is partially loaded as shown above in the screen.

Comment: Please also check the list of modules. For that there are a couple of ways one of them is to create a phpinfo page [check here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) then you can compare the modules that you have in your system with the requirements from muy first [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html). Depending on what is missing the way to install is also different, I can help more then if required. If my comments have been useful, please mark them as useful like I did with yours.

Comment: checked again, these all modules are already installed. Magneto before installation performs a system check, if all required modules are not installed, it will not allow installation.

Comment: There has to be something in some of the logs. If there is nothing, then "again" something is not working as it should. Make sure that apache is configured to log the errors. If apache is version `2.4`. you can chenge the LogLevel to debug or trace7 or trace8 for even more details check out [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel). That will show you details If nothing seems problematic there, you can then you can then turn to php.ini, where the problem is more likely to be make sure `display_errors = on`
test other php code that you know has problems and shows errors

Comment: Not seems to be related with Aapche or PHP. Its more a Magento error and Magento exceptionHandler not allowing to pass actual error on user screen. Will have to expose that handler to allow actual error to come up on screen along with file and line no.

Comment: Magento is not done for Windows, you might be right. I found posts about people who 'successfully' deployed on windows; included [this](https://cloudkul.com/blog/magento-2-1-installation-windows/). I can't say if true. I have only installed on Linux. You will need to debug that or other stack. I run Mac, but what I did is that I ran it with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for file sync and configs etc and virtualized [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with Linux. If they do not make the windows version you might be wasting a lot of time, they should have good reasons not to.